# What's missing in "The discovery of magnetic effects of coals made possible to measure an electric current"?

Tags: past-simple, time

I have done some English test and met the following sentence:

> The discovery of magnetic effects of coals **made possible** to
>   measure an electric current.

The answer book says that something wrong with "made possible". But it seems OK for me.

Could anybody explain what is incorrect there?

Comment: 'made it possible' could be the answer but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, I second you @eu2015 You *make something* possible.

Comment: Is this multiple choice or a written answer?

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost It is multiple choice question (you have to chose which part of a sentence is incorrect). I've tried to google this expression and, indeed, It seems, that the expression isn't used without object (it or something like this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"to make (something) possible" is **transitive**. It must have an object.

In

> The discovery of magnetic effects of coals made possible to measure an electric current.

the sentence is ungrammatical due to the object of "made (something) possible", in this case being an "it", being missing.

The correct sentence is:

> The discovery of magnetic effects of coals made **it** possible to measure an electric current.

Answer (score 0):

> The discovery of magnetic effects of coals **made** ***it*** **possible** to measure an electric current.
>
> It was possible **to measure** an electric current.
> The discovery of magnetic effects of coals **made possible** the measurement of electric current.

**made possible to measure** has two verbs competing with each other, they need to be separated somehow.

Comment: The verb cluster isn't the problem.

Comment: e.g. "It was impossible to complete." is valid.